# How can I create Several Pages with Several layouts in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, layout

I need to create two pages in wordpress with two different layouts. So what should I do to achieve that. I should create two php files, like page1.php, and page2.php then layout it separately, or what should I do to do that.

Please see the layout which I drow it to understand what I'm asking about.

Thanks in advance, for your help.

[image: The layout]

Comment: I answered a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9545646/762628 Thank you,
Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is custom page template:

http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2007/12/26/multiple-wordpress-page-layouts-in-one-single-template/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Sorry for being late in reply.

Answer (score 0):

you can create two different php file with different styles and each php file start with:

```
<?php
 /*
 Template Name: you_template_name
 */
 ?>
```

for example replace `you_template_name` with `theme1` and `theme2`
then when you try to create a new page you can use one of these themes

[image]

in these case I create two theme `fan template` and `news template` for my site addition of my default template