# How to create a custom page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I to create a custom page in Wordpress 3.0. Give me any link of tutorial.

Comment: definitely should be migrated to Wordpress.stackexchange

Answer (score 10):

WordPress provides a clever way to do this called Custom Page Templates. To create a WordPress Page Template, you’ll need to use your text editor. Go to the directory on your server where you installed WordPress, and then navigate to the directory of your theme. Usually that looks something like this: “/wp-content/themes/default” where “default” is your theme name.

That’s where you will create your custom page template file. Create a file called “cover_page.php” and add the following code to it:

```
 <?php
 /*
 Template Name: Cover Page
 */
 ?>

 <?php get_header(); ?>

 Here's my cover page!

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

more details read this

http://www.expand2web.com/blog/custom-page-template-wordpress/

Answer (score 3):

To add to the answers above, one good way is to open a text editor (I like notepad++) and copy and paste the content of the page.php file into a new file, including the php template name code in one of the previous examples.

Call it something unique (like custom_page1.php ) and upload this file via ftp to your active theme folder inside your wordpress install on your server. You can use filezilla for this or another FTP program.

Refresh your editor page in wordpress and you should see your template listed with the others on the right.

Now when you publish a page you can choose this template from the dropdown menu on the side panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) feature of wordpress to create a custom page.

Answer (score 0):

1. First create page using pages->add new.Then,give title (for e.g. aboutus). Then click
     Publish on right side of the window(no content is needed for the custom page).
2. Then,on left side of window click Appearance->Menus.
3. In menus window,on left side you will see Pages heading,in that click Most Recent and
     check aboutus page. Then it will be shown on right side window.
4. Then,on left above Pages heading, you will see Custom Links, in that enter # in URL textbox
     and aboutus in Label textbox. Then click Add to Menu button.
5. Done. You will see the menu as custom on right side of the window and then click save menu 
     button at the bottom right.
6. Then to check, on left top of the window click the website or your blog name. You will see 
     the menu. Click on it. No changes will occur.

That's it, done!

Answer (score -2):

Here are some plugins you can use while creating what you need then you can turn them off or remove them.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-file-duplicator/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-file-maker/

Very easy way to do what you need.

Comment: This does not seem to be an appropriate answer. No explanation, no reason for plugins at all here.

Answer (score -3):

This is a very simple part of WordPress theme development, I suggest giving the documentation (the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page)) a good read before going any further. There are also a tonne of great WordPress tutorial sites out there that will get you heading in the right direction.

Comment: "This is a very simple part of WordPress theme development", why not write that simple piece of code here? so it helps who have already viewed codex

Comment: I answered the question as asked. That's why.